# Inconsistencies in sign extension when shifting signed int vs short

Tags: c

```
int main(){
  signed int a = 0b00000000001111111111111111111111; 
  signed int b = (a << 10) >> 10;
  // b is: 0b11111111111111111111111111111111

  signed short c = 0b0000000000111111; 
  signed short d = (c << 10) >> 10;
  // d is: 0b111111

  return 0;
}
```

Assuming `int` is 32 bits and `short` is 16 bits,

Why would `b` get sign extended but `d` does not get sign extended?
I have tested this with gdb on x64, compiled with gcc.

In order to get `short` sign extended, I had to use two separate variables like this:

```
  signed short f = c << 10;
  signed short g = f >> 10;
  // g is: 0b1111111111111111
```

Comment: Just a guess, but possibly the optimizer realizes that `signed short d = (c << 10) >> 10;` has no observable behaviour.  But using two variables means there is a sequence point so then there is?

Comment: Here is an  MVCE: https://godbolt.org/z/hzGaW6Pro

Comment: If you print `sizeof(c<<10)` it prints the number of bytes in an int so it really is integer promotion.

Comment: Note that binary literals are not (yet — as of Feb 2020 draft standard) a part of standard C (but they are a part of standard C++).  Using the `0b0001` type notation is using an extension to the standard that is widely supported but not standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `signed short`, when an integer type smaller than `int` is used in an expression it is (in most cases) **promoted** to type `int`.  This is spelled out in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or
> `unsigned int` may be used
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less
>   than  or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`,`int`,`signed int`,or `unsigned int`.
>
> If  an `int` can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as
> restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is
> converted  to  an `int`; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an
> `unsigned int`. These  are  called  the *integer promotions* All
> other  types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions

And this promotion specifically happens in the case of bitwise shift operators as specified in section 6.5.7p3:

> **The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.**  The type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.   If  the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or  is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

So the `short` value 0x003f is promoted to the `int` value 0x0000003f and the left shift is applied.  This results in 0x0000fc00, and the right shift gives a result of 0x0000003f.

The `signed int` case is a bit more interesting.  In this case you're left-shifting  a bit with the value 1 into the sign bit.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per 6.5.7p4:

> The  result  of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit  positions;
> vacated  bits  are  filled  with zeros.  If `E1` has  an  unsigned
> type,  the  value  of  the  result  is *E1×2<sup>E2</sup>*, reduced
> modulo one  more  than  the  maximum  value  representable  in  the
> result  type.  **If `E1` has  a  signed type  and  nonnegative  value,
> and *E1×2<sup>E2</sup>* is  representable  in  the  result  type,
> then  that  is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.**

So while the output you get for the `signed int` case is what you might expect it to be, it's actually undefined behavior and so you can't depend on that result.

Comment: How about larger values like int64? do the remain as is?

Comment: @Dan Those are of a larger rank than `int`, so no promotion.

Comment: The moral of the story is: Don't apply shift operations to signed integer types. These traps are the reason why the MISRA rules specifically forbid it - in the old MISRA-2004 standard, this is rule 12.7.

Answer (score 2):

`short` is automatically converted to `int` by the *integer promotions*, per C 2018 6.5.7 3:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands…

So `(c << 10)` shifts an `int` `0b111111` left 10 bits, yielding (in your C implementation) the 32-bit `int` 0b00000000000000001111110000000000. The sign bit in that is zero; it is a positive number.

When you do `signed short f = c << 10;`, the result of `c << 10` is too big to fit in a `signed short`. It is 64,512, which is above the largest value your `signed short` can represent, 32,767. In an assignment, the value is converted to the type of the left operand. Per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, the conversion is implementation-defined. GCC defines this conversion to wrap modulo 65,536 (two the power of the number of bits in the type). So converting 64,512 yields 64,512 − 65,536 = −1024. So `f` is set to −1024.

Then, in `f >> 10`, you are shifting a negative value. As `signed short`, `f` is still promoted to `int`, but this conversion keeps the value, resulting in an `int` value of −1024. This is then shifted. This shift is implementation-defined, and [GCC defines it to shift with sign extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation). So the result of `-1024 >> 10` is −1.

Comment: But I have asked to shift a `short` value, why is it promoting it to an int? and how can I force similar behaviour as int?

Comment: Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/509868) - look for "integer promotions".

Comment: @Dan: You cannot ask C to shift a `short` value. In shift expressions, and in most C expressions, `short` operands are automatically converted to `int`. There is no way in C to express a shift of a `short` value. (In a C implementation where `short` and `int` are the same width, you could get the same result, although technically the shift is still done on an `int` value.)

Comment: How about larger values like int64? do the remain as is?

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
> type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

Thus this value

```
signed short c = 0b0000000000111111;
```

in the expression used in this declaration

```
signed short d = (c << 10) >> 10;
```

is promoted to the integer type `int`. As the value is positive then the promoted values is also positive.

Thus this operation

```
c << 10
```

does not touch the sign bit.

On the other hand this code snippet

```
signed int a = 0b00000000001111111111111111111111; 
signed int b = (a << 10) >> 10;
```

has undefined behavior because according to same section of the C Standard

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
> nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
> then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.**